# Formatting of logstash data for Graphite

Tags: logstash, graphite

I create logs of event counters from multiple servers in json format and then use logstash to put the counters into Graphite/Grafana.  This works, but I am not seeing the desired format in Grafana.  I want to be able to display multiple counters together based on the server.  Right now everything shows up in the first metric (including the server).  If I select the server, there is not a 2nd metric that is available to display the counter.  I am thinking that the format I am sending to Graphite is not correct.

This is one log.  Each line is a server (same server in each log), a date and a counter.  I can change the log format if needed.

```
{"Server":"10.254.70.52","@timestamp":"2016-05-13T20:58:24.0920228Z","oneLevelSearchOps":"11.07"}
{"Server":"10.254.70.52","@timestamp":"2016-05-13T20:58:24.0920228Z","searchOps":"12.92"}
{"Server":"10.254.70.52","@timestamp":"2016-05-13T20:58:24.0920228Z","errors":"0"}
```

This is the logstash .conf file

```
input {
 file {
  path => "/home/local/scott/difData-10.254.70.51.txt"
  codec => "json"
  sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  start_position => "beginning"
 }
}
output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 graphite{
  codec => "plain"
  fields_are_metrics => true
  host => "127.0.0.1"
  port => "2003"
 }
}
```

Using fields_are_metrics is needed or nothing is sent to Graphite.  sincebd_path and start_position are for debugging.

Here is one line from the stdout

```
{
         "Server" => "10.254.70.51",
     "@timestamp" => "2016-05-13T21:28:40.918Z",
 "modifyEntryOps" => "0.10",
       "@version" => "1",
           "path" => "/home/local/NV/sfoley/difData-10.254.70.51.txt",
           "host" => "lab-graphite"
}
```

Should Graphite be able to interpret this correctly?  Since I am adding more data to the log I would rather change the json formatted log rather than adding filters to the logstash .conf file for each counter if that is required, but I could do either.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I looked more into Graphite and changed the log to have only one entry (besides the date) with the server name and counter data separated by a period.  So server.counter This gave me what I wanted.

```
{"@timestamp":"2016-05-13T20:59:37.5815457Z","predr01.oneLevelSearchOps":"5.6"}
```